# Click Function not working in Selenium Driver C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I don't quite understand why this isn't working. (Win Forms Selenium Firefox webdrivers C#)

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("video")).Click();
```

There is multiple ClassName's with "video" in the html, so that might be the problem.

Here is the HTML Code for the site

```
<div class="video">
    <a style="background-image: url(&quot;http://pthumbnails.5min.com/10370971/518548518_c_240_135.jpg&quot;);" href="/watch/psychic-intervention-help-from-baby-amanda-518548518" data-id="518548518">
        <span>'Psychic Intervention': Help From Baby Amanda</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Everything in the HTML there beside video changes everytime. Please and Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div is not the element you want to click on, if you want to open the link. You need to click on the link (the <a> element) inside the div.

If you do not know what the link text or URL will be, but you know that it is in a div with the class "video", you can find the  element by its xpath, by looking for the first <a> tag after the div with a video class.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='video']/a")).Click();
```

FindElement also always picks the first element in the DOM which matches the criteria, which is fine if you just want to click on any video link.

However, if there are more than one divs with the class video that have <a> elements, and you want to click on a specific video link, you may want to use driver.FindElement**s** to get all the video links, compare the information, and click on the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since, there are mutiple class names with **"video"**, you need to segregate your xpath to make it point to the relevant element.

Below are the ways to do it:

**1-** By using the **div with video classname and the innerHTML/text inside the span tag** (Assuming there is only 1 such instance of innerHTML/text in the whole page):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='video']//span[contains(text(),'Help From Baby Amanda ')]")).Click();
```

**2-** By using the **'a' tag's unique attribute 'data-id'** (Assuming that data-id is, in fact,  UNIQUE):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-id='518548518']")).Click();
```

**3-** By using the **'a' tag and span tag's innerHTML/text** (Assuming there is only 1 such instance of innerHTML/text in the whole page):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/span[contains(text(),'Help From Baby Amanda ')]")).Click();
```

**4-** By using the **span tag's innerHTML/text only** (Assuming there is only 1 such instance of innerHTML/text in the whole page):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Help From Baby Amanda')]")).Click();
```

**NOTE:- There are multiple ways to do it. Above are the ways that I could think of, based on the HTML code snippet given.**